# replace a word present in dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a word C++ and +. I want to remove only + if it is not attached with any other word. So basically I want to remove + and not C++. I want to apply this condition on the whole dataframe.

Can someone please tell me how to do it.

I have tried doing `df['Decrip']=df['Decrip'].str.replace('+',' ')` but this removes each word having +. So C++ becomes C which I don't intend to do.

Comment: Depending on the other data in your DataFrame, I suggest looking into negative lookbehinds using regular expressions to help solve this. If you know the only two places a + can appear are stand alone or in C++, then you could use `DataFrame.where()`.

Comment: Add small sample of  data to the question.

Comment: Hi, I have added a small sample of the dataset. I want to remove + which is on the last line. So if + is not attached to  a word it should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex `(?<!\w|\+)\+`, it has negative lookbehind assertion to find the occurrence that has `+` but not to match `+` of `c++`:

```py
df['Decrip']=df['Decrip'].str.replace('(?<!\w|\+)\+',' ', regex=True)
```

[**Example at regex-101**](https://regex101.com/r/IAUlVI/1)

You can also replace `+` directly:

```py
df['Decrip']=df['Decrip'].str.replace(' + ', ' ', regex=False)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot the problem is solved. This has also enlightened me on negative lookbehind assertion which I wasn't aware.

Comment: Can you please explain negative lookbehind assertion logic.

Comment: `(?<!\w|\+)\+` means it will match `+` only if it isn't preceded by `\w|\+` where `\w` means any word character and `\+` means the `+` character, and they are connected by pipe `|` which means OR.

Answer (score 0):

pd.DataFrame.str.replace
accept Regex. I cannot answer exactly which Regex format should you use as I need more information about it. But you can figure out how to use Regex using this link.

https://regex101.com/